# Eigenvalues of A+B and AB

Tags: linear-algebra

I was studing eigenvalues and I have the following doubt.
When does sum of  eigenvalues of A and B provide eigenvalue of A+B and product of eigenvalues of A and B provide eigenvalue of AB.

Comment: This is true if $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable with respect to the same basis. (This may not be the most general condition though.)

Comment: In other words, it's quite rare in general for this to be the case.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  That there exist some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ and some eigenvalue $\mu$ of $B$ such that $\lambda + \mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A+B$?  Or every eigenvalue of $A+B$ is the sum of an eigenvalue of $A$ and an eigenvalue of $B$? Or is it for every eigenvalue of $A$ and every eigenvalue of $B$?  The latter will be difficult, because if the matrices are $n \times n$ there might be as many as $n^2$ values of $\lambda + \mu$, and they can't all be eigenvalues of $A+B$.